# Not able to run test.xml file through maven and command line in java selenium

Tags: java, maven, testng, pom.xml

I want to run `test.xml` file through maven and command line. My `test.xml` has 4 classes but unfortunately 'mvn test' command only picks one class.

Below is my project structure.
[image: Project structure]

And here is the code for `pom.xml`

```
<groupId>com.mobikon.commontestapp</groupId>
<artifactId>commontestapp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>bintray</name>
        <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
        <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>

    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<profiles>

    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>


                    <configuration>
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                                <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                                <value>false</value>
                            </property>
                            <property>
                                <name>listener</name>
                                <value>org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter, org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter</value>
                            </property>
                        </properties>

                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>test.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <!--<workingDirectory>target/</workingDirectory>-->
                    </configuration>

                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And Here is code for `test.xml`

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Mobikon Automation Tests" verbose="1" >

    <test name="mEngage" >
        <classes>
            <class name="mengage.tests.LoginScenarios"></class>
            <class name="mengage.tests.PurchaseCreditsTest"></class>
            <class name="mengage.tests.VerifyTotalCustomers"></class>
            <class name="mengage.tests.VerifyCredits"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

So now if I run maven from the command line this is the output.It is taking only PurchaseCredits class.

Command - `mvn clean test`

If I run from IntelliJ directly it is running properly, so the only issue I am facing is I am not able to run a proper `test.xml` file from maven

after mvn -Ptest clean test, this is the screenshot for Maven
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtY05.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must activate the profile which activates the appropriate `surefire` configuration:

```
mvn -Ptest clean test
```

By default, `surefire` only run `Test*` and `*Test` classes. That explains why only `PurchaseCreditsTest` is taken in your case.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help.. but now i am getting error that test.xml is not a valid file.. Can you please help on same

Comment: What is saying the xml fail is wrong? IntelliJ and/or maven? In case of IntelliJ only, try with a more recent version because yours may embed a too old testng version.

Comment: I am using Intellij as tool with Maven framework. And in pom.xml i have mentioned
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

But still the error remain same.

**"There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: Suite file D:\repos\mobikontestapp\src\test\java\test.xml is not a valid file"**

Comment: Could you share the output of `mvn -e -Ptest clean test`?

Comment: maven is looking for the suite in the default folder where your file doesn't exist. Just replace `test.xml` by `${project.basedir}\test.xml`. Fyi, the common folder for suites is `src/test/resources`.

Comment: Hey Juherr, thanks for this.. actually i gave a wrong path for test.xml, so i changed it and now its working fine..